# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (14, 14), indices imply (15, 15)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting the following error when trying to run the code below

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (14, 14), indices imply (15, 15)

```
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm):
    cm = cm[::-1]
    cm = pd.DataFrame(cm, columns=classes, index=classes[::-1])

    fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z=cm.values, x=list(cm.columns), y=list(cm.index), colorscale='ice', showscale=True, reversescale=True)
    fig.update_layout(width=500, height=500, title='Confusion Matrix', font_size=16)
    fig.show()

import plotly.figure_factory as ff
plot_confusion_matrix(cm)
```

Does anyone know how this can be resolved?

Comment: You should first learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ;)